# Python - split string into two columns

Tags: python, string, collections

Let's say I have this string:

```
"""line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8"""
```

I want to write a function to split it into two equal-sized columns represented by a single string, like so:

```
"""line1 line5
line2 line6
line3 line7
line4 line8"""
```

I can split the string in two like this:
s1,s2 = s[:len(s)//2], s[len(s)//2:]

But then I'm unsure on how to combine them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take what you've got and then:

```
>>> s ="""line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8"""
>>> s1, s2 = s[:len(s)//2], s[len(s)//2:]
>>> '\n'.join([' '.join(x) for x in zip(s1.split('\n'),s2[1:].split('\n'))])
'line1 line5\nline2 line6\nline3 line7\nline4 line8'
```

Nasty one-liner, but that's the basic premise, just use `zip` to pair the sequence items up and then you can `join` them back together.

Answer (score 3):

```
s='''line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8'''

lines=s.split()
halflen = len(lines)/2
columns = '\n'.join(' '.join((lines[x],lines[x+halflen])) for x in range(halflen))
```

Comment: (As an aside to the O.P. - you may want to use string formatting to pad the columns, assuming the real lines aren't all the same length.)

Comment: @mgilson there's always `itertools.izip_longest`.

Comment: Isn't this the wrong result?  First line that OP wants is `line1 line5`, first line here is `line1 line2`.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you split into lines first.

```
lines = s.splitlines()
s1, s2 = lines[:len(lines) // 2], lines[len(lines)//2:]
"\n".join(map(" ".join, zip(s1, s2)))
```

This works for an even number of lines. When the number of lines is odd, use `itertools.izip_longest` instead of `zip` and

```
def join(s1, s2):
    return s1 if s2 is None else " ".join((s1, s2))
```

instead of `" ".join` (you can inline this if you like cryptic oneliners).

Comment: I would advise using a tuple inside your `join` function instead of a list (i.e. `(s1, s2)` instead of `[s1, s2]`)

Comment: @mgilson: why? I prefer `([])` to `(())`.

Comment: +1 for noting that `zip()` will drop the last item when lines is odd.

Comment: 1) tuples are faster to create.  2) tuples are more suited to making constants compared to lists which exist to be mutated -- but I do agree that `([])` looks prettier than `(())`

Comment: @mgilson: indeed, two-tuple construction is apparently some 4x faster. Changed to `()` and it's still readable. Thanks.

Comment: @larsmans -- Yeah, I was surprised when I did some timings on my code and learned the speed difference between the 2.  tuples also take less memory, although that's less important in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This would put them in order:

```
string= string.split('\n')
string2= ""
for line in string:
    string2= string2 + line + " "
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an even number of lines and that both `s1` and `s2` are the same size, you can combine them as follows:

```
lines = [s1[index] + ' ' + s2[index] for index, val in enumerate(s1)]
'\n'.join(lines)
```

You can also concatenate both of those steps, but I left them separated for clarity.

If your strings are differing in length, you're going to need to put some conditionals and it'll get a little messy.